# Method of "cooperatively" terminating a WCF service (basic HTTP, non-duplex)

Tags: wcf, iis, basichttpbinding, cancellation, long-running-processes

I have a WCF service that takes a *long* time to run. (For the sake of this question I am not interested in breaking up the service call.)

However, when a client disconnects forcibly the WCF service will continue to run to completion - even if the client will never receive the response.

I've found information about reliable messaging (which does not seem to apply here), duplex channels/behaviors (which I don't want to implement or require), and understand how it's possible to "break up" the service requests.

However, I was wondering if there might not be a "simple" method like the CancellationPending property of a background worker, the service would then look something like so:

```
while (!WCFRequest.CancellationPending && !FinishedWithLongOperation) {
   DoOnePartOfTheLongOperation();
}
```

If not, is there any way to add such? Or even kick the WCF thread with a harsh exception (ie. TheadInterruptedException)?

The service itself is designed to be fully idempotent wrt the completed work and reporting of such.

---

The WCF service is hosted in IIS 7, which I suspect may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a WCF Service that is *hosted in IIS* as an HTTP/HTTPS end-point I am using [HttpResponse.IsClientConnected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which Works Here (TM).

*Note:* This depends on the ability of the hosting server (eg. IIS) to correctly detect a disconnect. In general these must be orderly disconnects. YMMV.

The code is then functionally equivalent to:

```
while (!FinishedWithLongOperation) {
    if (Connection.ClientConnectedStatus == ClientStatus.Disconnected) {
       throw new Exception("Client definitely disconnected!");
    }
    DoOnePartOfTheLongOperation();
}
```

Notes:

- "Connection" is injected via Dependency Injection (so it could theoretically be altered to other stacks) and ..
- .. ClientConnectedStatus returns one of {Connected, Disconnected, Unknown}; aborting only occurs when the client is "definitely disconnected" so that ..
- .. if there is no IIS / HTTPContext then ClientConnectedStatus will always return Unknown and prevent potential false not-Connected situations (eg. if hosted otherwise).